# Determine the integral surface passing through a curve.

Tags: integration

Determine the integral surface for the partial differential equation:
$$2z(xp+yq)+x^2+y^2-z^2=0$$
Passing through the curve:$$ x+y+z=0$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

I solved this equation by Lagrange method and got the solutions
$$
\begin{cases}
c_{1}=\dfrac{y}{x} \\ 
c_{2}=\dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I have to find an equation in $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ using the given curve and then find the final solution. I need to know how to proceed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I will be assuming your solutions are correct....

Make use of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in your $c_2$ , you have $\frac{1}{x}=c_2$ now, take $x=t$, $y=-t$ and $z=0$, obviously these values satisfies your curve from there you'll have $\frac{c_1}{x} = c_2$ putting back the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ gives the required solution.....